# Error with block built on XXX: Import failed: Unexpected epoch change

Tags: parachain, rococo, substrate-parachain-template, epoch

I'm trying to prepare a local parachain testnet. However, when I run two nodes at the same time, although the two nodes recognise each other no new blocks are added and I get this error:

```
Error with block built on 0x8d39cb0a86cceeeae7861dcc2b19fe9d8db94b8481ea50fd13093c7e632dc101: Import failed: Unexpected epoch change
```

Any idea how to fix this?

Comment: You can also build a testnet pretty quickly using https://github.com/paritytech/zombienet

Answer (score 2):

I think this is an error from the relaychain, not the parachain.

I guess the reason is that your relaychain was stopping producing blocks for a long time. Which doesn't meet BABE requirement.

Try to clean the DB.

Comment: How do I clean the DB?

Comment: Just remove the data dir. If you specify the `--base-dir` or `-d` then there it is. If not, on Linux it will be `~/.local/share/<chain name>`, on Mac it will be `~/Library/Application Support/<chain name>`.

Comment: or run with `--dev` which will implicitly use `--tmp` flag to use a fresh db each time.

Comment: IMHO `--dev` is not a good choice, as he is on relaychain env. `--dev` will build a brand new genesis state. Which may cause some syncing issues. But if `--chain` could override the `--dev`'s default chain, that's fine.

Comment: I have the same issue and I wanted to solve it without removing the data dir (for obvius reason). Is there any other solution possible?

Comment: No, that's impossible. Unless you modify the consensus engine. BTW, you can use the latest version. No more `unexpected epoch change` in the future.

Comment: @AurevoirXavier Hi, So we are facing some issue with our testnet for some time  are blocks not being produced, I saw at least 5 of the validators got slashed and many peers got removed from the network all together (100+), we tried to get the chain back up but nothing worked yet, while testing on local I found this error "unexpected epoch change". so does this mean if this happen, the chain won't be able to recover and the only  choice is to restart the network. Seems priority would be to update the code to latest substrate version.